# Symfony 3 routing annotation set homepage

Tags: php, symfony, routes, symfony-3.2

Right now my homepage is the `DefaultController`:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
```

But I'd like the default to be in my blog controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/blog/index", name="blog_index")
 */
    public function indexAction() {
```

I realise I could just set this route to `/`, but what I'd like is for both `/blog/index` and `/` to route to the same action (displaying the `/blog/index` url if possible).

I've had a look for previous answers, but I can't find one that deals specifically with annotations.

Right now I'm just redirecting from the `DefaultController` but that feels slightly hacky - does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried the following in your blog controller?

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 * @Route("/blog/index", name="blog_index")
 */
public function indexAction() { ... }
```

Comment: Nice solution. Thailandia you!

Comment: This doesn't appear to work if I use the url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/index` which returns no route, if I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` the url changes to: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7Bblog/index%7D` and the route works, but I'm assuming those extra characters are causing the problem? When those encode the url is: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/{blog/index}` which matches the route exactly.

Comment: I just updated the solution, I begin to misunderstanding thinking about Symfony's 2.x version, now it's correct.

Comment: This the best solution that i found to work with Symfony 5